# Verliog: Different Outputs when using an intermediate variable for Arithmetic Shift

Tags: verilog

Why is out1 any different from out2

```
module diff_outputs(in,out1,out2);
input in;
output out1,out2,out3;

wire [8:0] in, out1, out2;
wire [8:0] interm;


assign out1 = in>>>4 + in[3];

assign interm = in>>>4;
assign out2 = interm + in[3];

endmodule
```

out1 and out2 are the same for positive inputs. But for negative inputs, out1 is positive while out2 is negative (so effectively the shift operator in out1 is performing a logical shift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused by the way that Verilog deals with unsigned and signed arithmetic. Verilog is very liberal, but because of that you need to be familiar with the detail of how it works. 3 such details relevant to this case are:

> part selects are always *unsigned*

and

> unbased integer literals are *signed*

and

> if you mix signed and unsigned values, *unsigned* arithmetic is done

So, with this expression

```
assign out1 = (in>>>4) + in[3];
```

`in[3]` is a part select and so is unsigned. Therefore, unsigned arithmetic is used for the whole expression and so a *logical shift* is used. (With a logical shift right, zeros are added from the left.) If however, you split this into two expressions:

```
assign interm = in>>>4;
assign out2 = interm + in[3];
```

then *signed* arithmetic is used for the first expression (because both `in` and `4` are signed), so an *arithmetic shift* is used. (With an arithmetic shift right, the left hand bit is _sign_extended_, so in this case ones are added from the left.) The second expression is a mixed of signed (`interm`) and unsigned (`in[3]`), so unsigned arithmetic is used (as before).

So, when you do everything is one expression there is a mix of unsigned and signed, so unsigned arithmetic is used and so a logical shift right is done. However, when you use two expressions the expression for the shift is purely signed, so signed arithmetic is used and so an arithmetic shift right is done.

You'll find this

```
assign out3 = $signed(in>>>4) + in[3];
```

behaves the same way as the two-expression case, because the `$signed()` system function forces an arithmetic shift to be done.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6CGk

Comment: I think you meant this `assign out3 = $signed(in)>>>4 + in[3];`

Comment: @mmh98 I don't think I did - without the brackets, the operator predidence gives a completely different result. With brackets - `assign out4 = ($signed(in)>>>4) + in[3];` you get the same result as `out1` - a logical shift is done (the `$signed` system function call is doing nothing - `in` is already signed).  See https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6CGk.

Comment: Yeah the brackets need to be without the `>>>` like this : `$signed(in)>>>4` and not like this `$signed(in>>>4)` (the second one is what you wrote in your first answer)

Comment: I don't understand. `$signed(in>>>4)` is what I meant. `$signed(in)>>>4` gives the wrong answer, as does `($signed(in)>>>4)`. See https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6CGk. See IEEE 1800-2012 11.7 - "the $signed and $unsigned system functions are available for casting the
signedness of expressions ... $signed—returned value is signed". Am I misunderstanding your point?